# How to compute probability related to a difference of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, probability-distributions

I am studying Joint Probability Distributions and Random Samples.

I have a function for a probability distribution, defined as:

$ 
f(x, y) = K(x^2 + y^2)~~~~~~~~~ 20 \leq x \leq 30, ~~~20 \leq y \leq 30
$

and $0$ otherwise.

I want to compute the probability that the difference between $x$ and $y$ is at most $2$.

How can I approach this problem?

### Edit:

I know that the region to consider is that inside the two lines in the plot. But I don't understand how to define the boundaries inside the integrals.

[image: area]

Comment: How about first figuring out whether you are are being asked for $P(X-Y \leq 2)$ or $P(|X-Y| \leq 2)$?

Comment: I am being asked for the second, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, calculate $K$.  To do that, use the fact that $\int\int fdxdy=1$.
Secondly, draw the region, within $[20,30]\times[20,30]$, where $|x-y|\leq2$.  Express that region as double integrals of $f$.

Comment: **Hint:** It might be easier to use the complement : $\;\mathsf P(\lvert X-Y\rvert\leq 2) = 1-\mathsf P(\lvert X-Y\rvert > 2)$

Comment: I computed K. I updated the question with the plot of the region, but I am unable to translate this into the correct boundaries. Analytical solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: To add to Michael's answer and Graham Kemp's perceptive comment on it (and David K's answer which also says the same thing), you need integrate $f_{X.Y}(x,y)$ _only_ over the right triangular region with vertices $(22,20), (30,20),(30,28)$ (i.e. the region where $X-Y > 2$) and _double_ the answer since, by symmetry, the probability that $X-Y < -2$ is the same. So, one double integral instead of two to get $P(|X-Y| >2)$ instead of the more complicated integration over the hexagonal region corresponding to $P(|X-Y| \leq 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating over a hexagonal region (like the one in the middle of your diagram)
generally involves breaking the region up into smaller regions that have boundaries that are easier to deal with. For example, use vertical lines to cut off a piece on the left bounded below by the line $y=0$ 
and a piece on the right bounded above by the line $y = 30$,
leaving a parallelogram in the middle; then integrate each of these
three parts separately.

In this particular problem it might be easier to integrate the parts of the
distribution where the difference between $x$ and $y$ is *not* at most $2$,
and subtract those probabilities from $1$.
Then you just have to look at two triangular regions, one in the upper left corner and one in the lower right corner.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I ended up using the first answer given, together with Graham Kemp comment. I upvoted yours however. Thanks